How much minced meat can I get from a 100kg pig?
I want to make bulk minced meat and have it cheaper than retail.
I have had success in buying whole animals and using for meat, price is about half of normal retail price (even after all the losses like organs).
But how does that work for minced meat, which obviously won't have any bones in it at all?
How much minced meat can I get from say 100kg pig? I don't mind to have some fat in there.
A friend of mine told me you can even use skin, but I am doubtful.

I expect you will find what you want here https://livestock.extension.wisc.edu/articles/how-much-meat-should-a-hog-yield/

Thanks that is helpful. So if I take the cited "Boneless closely trimmed retail cuts" number it would be 65%? Other sources say 55% but I guess that just depends on the animal, how closely the fat trim is etc? There isn't any particular loss from the mincing process in itself I guess?

Using all meat from an entire pig for a single batch of minced meat would be very wasteful. Different cuts of pork have very different value and grinding the fancy cuts gives you a lot less value than using these pieces separately from the less attractive cuts.

@quarague thats a good point. Which parts are considered best for minced meat? Maybe I need to buy them in bulk somehow? Or I have to find a way to sell the good parts?
